# ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative when using if statements to compare lists of potentially different sizes

Tags: python

Im getting the error above "ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative"

What Im trying to do is to compare two lists, and print the common elements with no duplicates.

```
 import random

r1 = random.sample(range(1,10),5)
r2 = random.sample(range(1,10),15)
if len(r1) >= len(r2):
    print(r1, r2)
    print(set(x for x in r1 if x in r2))
if len(r1) < len(r2):
    print(r1, r2)
    print(set(x for x in r2 if x in r1))


# set it used to make sure no duplicates
#
```

What I tried to do was compare the length of the lists, and see which one was bigger and then used that list as the starting for the list comprehension, however, this throws me the error above. I can't quite figure out exactly why this doesn't work.

P.S: This is my first StackOverflow post so if you have any pointers for better questions next time I'm open to criticism.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to select *15* random samples from a `range(1, 10)`. That's more requested samples than the range is long, hence the error.

Comment: AH, thank you. after more messing around turns out the IF statements are useless.